# Report from ServiceNow to Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, servicenow

How do I schedule a task to generate a weekly report in **ServiceNow** and send as an email.

I want the same report to be sent to my **SharePoint** **site** automatically every week. How to integrate it ? Please help.

Comment: thanks for editing my question above. Am absolutely new to both ServiceNow and SharePoint , just seeking help from professionals here to do my assignment.

Comment: new to StackOverflow too :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to setup Incoming email on a Document Library in SharePoint and email a scheduled report to it from ServiceNow.

This also depends on ServiceNow being able to send email to this address.

You may need ServiceNow to have a VPN to your network with SharePoint, and you need Incoming email to be configured on your SharePoint install.

If those are working, you can do something like the following.

**SharePoint**

- Create a **Document Library**
- Go to **Library Settings**
- Open **Incoming E-Mail Settings**
- Change *Allow this document library to receive e-mail?* to **Yes**
- Give this an E-mail address: **reports@mysharepoint.com**

**SharePoint Security**

Consider how ServiceNow is sending email to you. If email is sent via their mail servers, you may need to set incoming email option

- *E-mail security policy* to **Accept e-mail messages from any sender**

In this case, be mindful of what email can be delivered to your network. This may allow unwanted emails coming in.

If ServiceNow uses your mail servers, you may be able to grant access to the Document Library for the user that is delivering your email. If so you may be able to set this

- *E-mail security policy* to **Accept e-mail messages based on document library permissions**

This is much more secure, but these things always depend on your environment and your needs.

**ServiceNow**

- Go to **Reports** > **View** / **Run**
- Open the report to be delivered
- Click the **dropdown** on the *Save* button
- Choose **Schedule**
- Fill out the Schedule form

  - Click the Users lock
  - In *Enter email address* put in the email to send to the Document Library (ex: *reports@mysharepoint.com*)
  - Run: **Weekly**
  - Choose the **Day** of the week and the **Time**
  - Subject: **My report**
  - Right click the header and choose **Save**

Test this by clicking **Execute Now** within the *Scheduled Report*

Comment: Awesome explanation. Thanks. Well, I don't find "•Open Incoming E-Mail Settings" in mine.  I do find Versioning Settings, Advanced Settings, Validation Settings,rating settings,Form settings etc but NOT EMAIL. Do I need to contact my admin to get it ?       Am successful in ServiceNow part though. Must fetch the report from SharePoint now.Thanks again.

Comment: The `Incoming E-Mail Settings` is under **Communications** on the right side of the Document Library settings. If you don't see it, Incoming email is probably not enabled and your admin may need to help set it up.

Comment: We use O365 -SharePoint Online and my admin just said we don't have that option on "online" version under Communications in Document Library Settings. Is there any other way , I can do in SharePoint Online version ? Thanks.

Comment: I found out meantime solution...I created a Site Mailbox and fwding the Report to Mailbox. I read from https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/svarukala/2016/05/27/sharepoint-online-incoming-email-alternatives/. Well, thanks for your prompt and detailed explanation.